# i have added dialect in hibernate properties but why i am getting "Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.oracl11gDialect"exception

Tags: java, hibernate

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <value>com.org.springsApps.Student</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">   
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.oracl11gDialect</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

i have added dialect name in xml file but it's asking again for dialect

Answer (score 1):

wrong class name in your xml: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: then you have typos on the classname or using an old hibernate version. dialect is part of hibernate framework so the class should be there

Answer (score 1):

`hibernate.dialect` setting needs to be a classname for a `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` subclass.  [Hibernate comes bundled with several dialects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) for some common RDBMS.

If your target database is Oracle 11g, then use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` as the setting value, per the table.